# Terraform: Resource 'aws_instance' not found for variable 'aws_instance.id'

Tags: amazon-ec2, automation, terraform, infrastructure

I have started using terraform to automate AWS resource provisioning for setting up k8s cluster. I am facing an issue when trying to refer aws_instance.id from aws_eip. Here are the useful details:

```
aditya@aditya-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/terraform-states$ terraform -v
Terraform v0.11.11
+ provider.aws v1.54.0
```

**1) aws-eip.tf**

```
resource "aws_eip" "nat" {
    instance = "${aws_instance.xenial.id}"
    vpc = true
    depends_on = ["aws_internet_gateway.esya_igw"]
}
```

**2) aws_inst.tf:**

```
resource "aws_instance" "xenial" {
    ami = "${var.aws_ami}"
    instance_type = "t3.large"
    ebs_optimized = true
    monitoring = true
    count = "8"
    key_name = "${var.aws_key_name}"
    tags{
        Name = "KubeVMCluster${count.index + 1}"
    }
}
```

**Expected Behavior**: AWS EIP must be able to refer to AWS Instance.
**Current Behavior**: We are getting this error:

```
aditya@aditya-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/terraform-states$ terraform plan
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_eip.nat: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_eip.nat: Resource 'aws_instance.xenial' not found for variable 'aws_instance.xenial.id'
```

I have tried to find a solution by referring to similar kind of issues in Github and elsewhere, but to no avail. According to me, I don't find anything problematic with the declarative code.

I need help in resolving this issue.

Regards

Aditya

Comment: Are both of these files in the same directory?

Comment: @KrisT sounds like you solved it yourself. Do you mind adding a solution and marking it as solved?